# SCHTASKS.EXE works inconsistently

Tags: windows-task-scheduler, windows-server-2016

I created a task remotely on ServerB and ServerC from ServerA using a command like this.

```
SCHTASKS.exe /Create /S server /RU domain\user /RP "password" /SC ONCE /TN task /TR D:\scripts\script.cmd /ST 00:00
```

I can run it remotely on serverB using a command like this.

```
SCHTASKS.EXE /RUN /S serverB /I /TN \task
```

But when I use this same command to run it on serverC I get `ERROR: The request is not supported.`

I can query it and delete it and re-create it on ServerC from ServerA, but I cannot run it.

I can RDP into ServerC and run it locally.

I am using a domain account that is a member of Administrators on all three servers.

All 3 servers are Windows Server 2016 Datacenter [Version 10.0.14393].

All 3 servers have the same version of `SCHTASKS.EXE` [Version 6.2.14393.0].

Other ways I have run scripts remotely:

I used to use `PSEXEC.EXE`, and it was the most reliable and consistent, but it has been banned at my company.

I have tried using Powershell and WinRS, but I get inconsistent results like get with SCHTASKS.

Comment: Sounds like a firewall issue that blocks certain RPC calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this on serverC :

- Run Windows Defender Firewall with Advanced Security
- Click Inbound Rules
- Find the four rules named "Remote Scheduled Tasks Management ..."
- Enable the rules that fit your context (probably the Domain ones)
- Enable the rules.

Note that you may also use the command :

```
wmic /node:serverC "cmd /c SCHTASKS.EXE /RUN /I /TN task"
```

Comment: Thank you! That should be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up removing the /I parameter from the command and I started getting consistent results. So far it has successfully run the task on over a dozen servers.